# Prevent of “Uncaught (in promise)” warning. How to avoid of 'catch' block? ES6 promises vs Q promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, es6-promise, q

My question consist of two parts:

## Part 1

According to standard ES6 `Promise` I see that I forced to use `catch` block everywhere, but it looks like copy/paste and looks weird.

Example:

I have some class which makes request to backend (lets call it `API` class).

And I have a few requirements for `API` class using:

**1)** I need to make requests in different parts of my application with single request errors processing:

```
// somewhere...
api.getUser().then(... some logic ...);

// somewhere in another module and in another part of app...
api.getUser().then(... some another logic...);
```

**2)** I want so 'then' blocks would work ONLY when 'getUsers' succeeded.

**3)** I don't want to write `catch` block everywhere I use `api.getUsers()`

```
api.getUser()
// I don't want following
.catch(e => {
    showAlert('request failed');
})
```

So I'm trying to implement single error processing inside of the class  for all "users requests"

```
class API {
    getUser() {
        let promise = makeRequestToGetUser();
        promise.catch(e => {
            showAlert('request failed');
        });
        return promise;
    }
}
```

...but if request fails I still forced to use `catch` block

```
api.getUser()
    .then(... some logic...)
    .catch(() => {}) // <- I forced to write it to avoid of “Uncaught (in promise)” warning
```

... otherwise I'll get “Uncaught (in promise)” warning in console. So I don't know the way of how to avoid of `.catch` block everywhere I use `api` instance.

Seems this comes from throwing error in such code:

```
// This cause "Uncaught error"
Promise.reject('some value').then(() => {});
```

May be you can say 'just return in your class "catched" promise'.

```
class API {
    getUser() {
        return makeRequestToGetUser().catch(e => {
            showAlert('request failed');
            return ... 
        });
    }
}
```

...but this contradict to my **#2** requirement.

See this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/promises-catch-block-question

So my 1st question is **how to implement described logic without writing `catch` block everywhere I use `api` call?**

## Part 2

I checked if the same `API` class implementation with `Q` library will get the same result and was **surprised** because I don't get `“Uncaught (in promise)” warning`. BTW it is more expectable behavior than behavior of native ES6 Promises.

In this page https://promisesaplus.com/implementations I found that `Q` library is implementation of Promises/A+ spec. But why does it have different behavior?
Does es6 promise respects Promises/A+ spec?

Can anybody explain why these libraries has different behavior, which one is correct, and how implement mentioned logic in case if "ES6 Promises implementation" is correct?

Comment: not really solving your problem, but the second parameter to `.then` is what to do on rejection.  e.g. you can do `.then(u => {…}, err => {})` to "ignore" the error

Comment: @SamMason thanks. Yes I know it. But in general this is the same, because I would forced to write `, e => {}` everywhere. BTW my be in future I will need to wrap my `API` class to some abstraction which makes some actions after request and return new promise. In this case I'll get the same problem again.

Comment: Please use **on-site** Stack Snippets, not off-site resources, for runnable demos.

Comment: *"See this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/promises-catch-block-question"* Again, please use the **on-site** Stack Snippets, rather than having part of your question not available here on-site. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Answer (score 2):

> I see that I forced to use catch block everywhere

No, you don't need to do that. Instead, *return* the promise created by `then` to the caller (and to that caller's caller, and...). Handle errors at the uppermost level available (for instance, the event handler that started the call sequence).

If that's still too many `catch`s for you, you can hook the `unhandledrejection` event and prevent its default:

```js
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    // You can use `event.reason` here for the rejection reason, and
    // `event.promise` for the promise that was rejected
    console.log(`Suppressed the rejection '${event.reason.message}'`);
});

Promise.reject(new Error("Something went wrong"));
```

The browser will trigger that event prior to reporting the unhandled rejection in the console.

Node.js supports this as well, on the `process` object:

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', error => {
  // `error` is the rejection reason
});
```

Note that you get the reason directly rather than as a property of an event object.

> So I don't know the way of how to avoid of `.catch` block everywhere I use `api` instance.

Surely the caller of `getUser` needs to know it failed? I mean, if the answer to that is really "no, they don't" then the event is the way to go, but really the code using `api` should look like this:

```
function useTheAPI() {
    return getUser()
        .then(user => {
            // Do something with user
        });
}
```

(or the `async` equivalent) so that the code calling `useTheAPI` knows that an error occurred; again, only the top-level needs to actually handle the error.

> Can anybody explain why these libraries has different behavior, which one is correct, and how implement mentioned logic in case if "ES6 Promises implementation" is correct?

Both are correct. Reporting unhandled exceptions entirely in userland (where libraries live) is hard-to-impossible to do such that there aren't false positives. JavaScript engines can do it as part of their garbage collection (e.g.: if nothing has a reference to the promise anymore, and it was rejected, and nothing handled that rejection, issue the warning).

Comment: T.J. Crowder you said "Handle errors at the uppermost level available" and "only the top-level needs to actually handle the error". But I use such class in different parts of app, btw somewhere It can be wrapped with another abstraction, so I don't have single "top-level" place where I can handle all errors of all promises. I'm not sure that understand you. Can you give an example?

Comment: @WebBrother - The example I gave in the answer was *"for instance, the event handler that started the call sequence"*. So if you had 10 event handlers and each one called 5 promise-returning functions, you'd have 10 `catch` handlers (but not 50! :-) ). Often that might be just `.catch(reportError);`, handing off to an appropriate error reporting mechanism. Other times, depending on what the event handler did before starting the async operation, it might be `.catch(error => { reportError(error); cleanup(); })` or similar.

Comment: T.J. Crowder Thank you! I got what you meant, but now the question why should I "handle errors at the uppermost level"? In my code example I already processed request error in `getUser` method. So why should I process it again in event handler?

Comment: @WebBrother - To avoid having to have error handlers in every function. Better to propagate errors (by returning the promise from `then`) so that error handling is in as few places as possible.

Comment: Two years have passed, and I still can not understand your answer. What do you mean by "return the promise created by then"? Can you modify my demo according to your idea?